# Как с помощью iptables ограничить скорость конкретным пользователям?

Tags: firewall, настройка, linux

Дайте, пожалуйста, примеры для командной строки и при работе в Webmin.

Answer (score 2):

webmin не знаю, да и не нужен он. Обычно народ пишет скрипты под себя. iptables + tc(traffic control) Например, мой скрипт такой:

```
#/bin/sh
IFACES='br-lan'
###################################################################
## Script for fast comfigure tc (Traffic Shaper)###################
###################################################################
if  test -z "$1"
then
    echo "Use start|stop|show"
fi
MODULES='sch_ingress sch_sfq sch_htb cls_u32 cls_fw'
if test "$1" = "show"
then
    if  test -z "$2"
    then
        echo "Use show [interface]"
        exit
    fi
    echo "#########Print qdisk################"
    echo '###'$2
    tc -s qdisc ls dev $2
    echo "#########Print class################"
    echo '###'$2
    tc -s class ls dev $2
    exit
fi
if test "$1" = "stop"
then
    for IFACE in $IFACES ; do
        tc qdisc del dev $IFACE root    2> /dev/null > /dev/null
        tc qdisc del dev $IFACE ingress 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
    done
    for i in $MODULES ; do
        rmmod $i
    done
    exit
fi
if test "$1" = "start"
then
    for i in $MODULES ; do
        insmod $i
    done
    for IFACE in $IFACES ; do
        ################IFACE################################################
        tc qdisc add dev $IFACE root handle 1: htb default 50
        tc class add dev $IFACE parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100Mbit burst 2k
        tc class add dev $IFACE parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 512kbit burst 2k
        tc qdisc add dev $IFACE parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 1
        tc class add dev $IFACE parent 1:1 classid 1:40 htb rate 99Mbit burst 2k
        tc qdisc add dev $IFACE parent 1:40 handle 40: sfq perturb 1                tc class add dev $IFACE parent 1:1 classid 1:50 htb rate 256kbit burst 2k
        tc qdisc add dev $IFACE parent 1:50 handle 50: sfq perturb 1
        tc class add dev $IFACE parent 1:1 classid 1:60 htb rate 15240kbit burst 2k
        tc qdisc add dev $IFACE parent 1:60 handle 60: sfq perturb 1                tc class add dev $IFACE parent 1:1 classid 1:70 htb rate 1028kbit burst 2k
        tc qdisc add dev $IFACE parent 1:70 handle 70: sfq perturb 1
        tc filter add dev $IFACE parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 30 fw flowid 1:30
        tc filter add dev $IFACE parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 40 fw flowid 1:40
        tc filter add dev $IFACE parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 50 fw flowid 1:50
        tc filter add dev $IFACE parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 60 fw flowid 1:60
        tc filter add dev $IFACE parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 70 fw flowid 1:70
    done
fi
#Traffic control
iptables -t mangle -F
#DOWNLOAD
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.2 -o br-lan -j MARK --set-mark 60
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.3 -o br-lan -j MARK --set-mark 30
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.4 -o br-lan -j MARK --set-mark 30
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.5 -o br-lan -j MARK --set-mark 40
#UPLOAD
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.2 -i br-lan -j MARK --set-mark 60
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.3 -i br-lan -j MARK --set-mark 50
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.4 -i br-lan -j MARK --set-mark 50
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.5 -i br-lan -j MARK --set-mark 40
```

Comment: Манипуляции с iptables у меня выполняются в отдельном скрипте

Answer (score 0):

iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.103 -m limit --limit 128k -j ACCEPT

iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.131 -m limit --limit 128k -j ACCEPT

iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.126 -m limit --limit 128k -j ACCEPT

iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.103 -j DROP

iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.131 -j DROP

iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.126 -j DROP

iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.103 -j LIMIT_DOWNLOAD

iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.131 -j LIMIT_DOWNLOAD

iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.126 -j LIMIT_DOWNLOAD

iptables-save

без tc!

Comment: а где описание цепочки LIMIT_DOWNLOAD?